# Is there an Rx operator like groupBy that only groups consecutive elements?

Tags: reactive-programming

I'd like a GroupBy that emits a new observable every time the key changes.  Is there such a thing?

Something like this pseudocode:

```
[1,3,5,2,4,3,7] groupByConsecutive? oddEven
```

would produce

```
Observable[Observable[1,3,5],Observable[2,4],Observable[3,7]]
```

Comment: Is the output an observable of observables? Code will always make it easier for us to understand.

Comment: Sorry, it's not a duplicate of the question I linked. I missed the fact that there is no `Replay` requirement.

Comment: @YacoubMassad - I changed the tag, I meant this as a question about Rx in general, not the dotnet implementation.  And yes, I need the result type to be Observable[Observable[_]].

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to come up with something that did not rely on a `Subject` but I think this will do what you want:

```
new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 3, 7 }
.ToObservable()
.Publish(let =>
    let
    .GroupByUntil(
        x => x % 2,
        group => let.SkipWhile(x => x % 2 == group.Key)))
```

You could refactor the above into a more general extension method like this:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<IGroupedObservable<TKey, TSource>> GroupByUntilChanged<TSource, TKey>(
        this IObservable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
        IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer = null)
    {
        comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;

        return 
            source
            .Publish(let =>
                let
                .GroupByUntil(
                    keySelector,
                    group => let.SkipWhile(x => comparer.Equals(keySelector(x), group.Key))));
    }
}
```

And then call it like so:

```
new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 3, 7 }
.ToObservable()
.GroupByUntilChanged(x => x % 2)
```

Comment: That looks really useful; the bad news is that as far as I can tell GroupByUntil is a dotnet extension and not part of standard Rx.  At least I'm not seeing anything about it in the documentation (http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html) (I originally used the wrong tag on the question; I've updated it)

Comment: Hmm - it looks like groupByUntil is implemented by php and js also, not just dotnet.

Comment: Oh no!  Well, I was able to come up with something similar to this using the `Window` function instead of `GroupByUntil` but it had the nasty problem of appending the first item in the next observable to the previous observable.  Are you using a particular flavor of reactive extensions?